# When I float my div to the left, it disappers, why?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this div, when I float it to the left, it disappears completely, why?

[see here](http://www.antosiaphotography.com/blog/)

Here is original CSS code (on wordpress platform):

```
}
.archive #primary,
.search #primary,
.blog #primary {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
```

The div loads, then disappears when I add this: `float:left;`

I am trying to get the sidebar to sit on the right while the content sits on the left, that's why I am adding this code.

Comment: Try also adding `position:relative;`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it's still happening

Comment: Ah, it's happening after the page is loaded so it's something in Javascript; probably something in wordpress. This is not a simple answer based on CSS...

Comment: Just to say what I mean, I saw the entire blog when it first loaded, and then the content jumped off to be invisible. But now when I reload I don't see the content at all.

Comment: Do you think it could be happening because I don't have the latest version installed?

Comment: er, just checking through your code right now... I don't see any way where float:left will NOT cause a problem with this. Why do you want the whole blog content to float:left?

Comment: Usually float:left tries to position smaller images or something so they don't take up a whole line of content. But for something very large and tall like this, you would want other things to float left of the main content.

Comment: Well, I just wanted the sidebar on the right hand side of the content, I am not sure how to put the sidebar on either side of the content. If I take out the float:left, then the sidebar just sits at the bottom, I will show you now

Comment: I changed max-width in the #primary to width and it fixed the problem, thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you can adjust to your specs.

```
#primary {
    width: 900px;
}
#secondary {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: changing Max-width to width seemed to do the trick, thank you :)

Comment: No problem.  As an FYI, you will want to start thinking about page speed, since you are using a lot of rich images, I prefer using Google Developer Page Speed Insights, here is your link:  http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.antosiaphotography.com%2Fblog%2F&tab=desktop.